# Do not show the node ids when displaying the graph

Tags: svg, graphviz, pygraph

I am displaying a `graph`. I have discovered the [attributes](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html). I am using successfully `URL`, `shape` and `color`. But I also want to output nodes without IDs (my IDs are too long to fit the display). So I have tried to set `label` to `""`, but still the `node id` is shown in the `svg` output. How can I prevent this? These are the attributes I am setting (in `python`):

```
[ 
  ('label', ''),
  ('URL', 'http://my.url.com'), 
  ('shape', 'octagon'),
  ('color', 'purple'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the URL conflicts with an empty label. A Short label must be configured if a URL is given.